# VBA Code to compare rows from two excel workbooks and then copy any that are different to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

We are using an SQL database for alarms on our SCADA which is updated by importing an excel file. We want to be able to compare the existing excel file with one that has been reviewed. However, both may have had changes made so we need to compare the two and know which rows are different. If any cell in a row has been changed or deleted it needs to copy the entire row to the new workbook to highlight the changes.

I am new to VBA code so have browsed the internet and found nothing that matches what I want. I have tried stitching together different code that each does part of what I want but not succeeding. The below code is the latest attempt but this doesn't copy it across if there are blanks, presumably as its looking for a value. It will also only copy the amount of columns dependent on the rows in file 1 which means it needs a minimum of 15 rows.

```
`Sub Compare_Two_Files()
SummaryFile = "U:\My Documents\Billet Project\Software\SCADA\Alarms Database\vba code.xlsx"
SummaryFile_Sheet = "Sheet1"
File1 = "U:\My Documents\Billet Project\Software\SCADA\Alarms Database\File1.xlsx"
File2 = "U:\My Documents\Billet Project\Software\SCADA\Alarms Database\File2.xlsx"
File1_Sheet = "Sheet1"
File2_Sheet = "Sheet1"
Set Workbook3 = Workbooks.Open(SummaryFile)
Set Workbook1 = Workbooks.Open(File1)
Set Workbook2 = Workbooks.Open(File2)
Set Rng1 = Workbook1.Worksheets(File1_Sheet).UsedRange
Set Rng2 = Workbook2.Worksheets(File2_Sheet).UsedRange
Count = 2
For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To Rng1.Columns.Count
If Rng1.Cells(i, j) <> Rng2.Cells(i, j) Then
For k = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
Workbook3.Worksheets(SummaryFile_Sheet).Cells(Count, k) = Rng2.Cells(i, k)
Next k
Count = Count + 1
Exit For
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub`
```

Comment: Do the files have the same number of rows and columns? Are the rows correctly associated with each other? If not, regarding the rows, which column(s) designates that they are the same data point? Your code kind of copies the rows only from the 2nd file. Is that the behavior that you require? If not, describe the exceptional cases including the meaning of *"this doesn't copy it across if there are blanks"* which could suggest that in this case, you want to copy from the 1st file.

Comment: They will always have the same number of columns (A-O). Currently there could be changes made to both, hence wanted to see all the differences. Column A should always be unique as this is alarm tag name. If a new alarm is added in either excel spreadsheet (new row) or deleted / changed i wanted to highlight it by copying to a new workbook. However, starting to think i need to simplify this and say one of the files is the master regardless, say File1, and then compare any changes to File2. The blanks would mean the row (alarm) has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieve Differences Between Two Worksheets

- Not tested!
- Avoiding the technicalities, it loops through each row of Master and using the 'unique ID', tries to find a match in Slave. If not found, copies the row from Master to Summary. If found, loops through the columns to find a difference. If found, copies both rows to Summary. Finally, it copies the rows of Slave that are not found in Master to Summary.

```vb
Sub RetrieveDifferences()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String _
        = "U:\My Documents\Billet Project\Software\SCADA\Alarms Database\"
    Const MASTER_FILE_NAME As String = "File1.xlsx"
    Const MASTER_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SLAVE_FILE_NAME As String = "File2.xlsx"
    Const SLAVE_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SUMMARY_FILE_NAME As String = "vba code.xlsx"
    Const SUMMARY_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const COLUMNS_ADDRESS As String = "A:O"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Source Master
    
    Dim mwb As Workbook:
    Set mwb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & MASTER_FILE_NAME)
    Dim mws As Worksheet: Set mws = mwb.Sheets(MASTER_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim mData() As Variant:
    mData = Intersect(mws.Columns(COLUMNS_ADDRESS), mws.UsedRange).Value
    Dim mrCount As Long: mrCount = UBound(mData, 1)
    mwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Source Slave
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: ' Source Slave
    Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & SLAVE_FILE_NAME)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SLAVE_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim sData() As Variant:
    sData = Intersect(sws.Columns(COLUMNS_ADDRESS), sws.UsedRange).Value
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(mData, 2)
    
    ' Write the unique values and row numbers to dictionaries.
    
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long
    
    Dim mdict As Object: Set mdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    mdict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    For r = 2 To mrCount
        Value = mData(r, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                mdict(Value) = r
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim sdict As Object: Set sdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sdict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Value = sData(r, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                sdict(Value) = r
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Loop through the master dictionary and compare the keys
    ' with the keys of the slave dictionary
    ' and populate the destination array accordingly.
    
    Dim dData() As Variant:
    ReDim dData(1 To mdict.Count + sdict.Count, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim Key As Variant, mr As Long, sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    Dim IsMasterFound As Boolean, IsSlaveFound As Boolean
    
    For Each Key In mdict.Keys
        If sdict.Exists(Key) Then ' found in both
            mr = mdict(Key)
            sr = sdict(Key)
            For c = 2 To cCount
                If StrComp(CStr(mData(mr, c)) <> CStr(sData(sr, c)), _
                        vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    IsMasterFound = True
                    IsSlaveFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
        Else ' not found in slave
            IsMasterFound = True
        End If
        If IsMasterFound Then
            IsMasterFound = False ' reset
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = mData(mr, c)
            Next c
        End If
        If IsSlaveFound Then
            IsSlaveFound = False ' reset
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
            Next c
            sdict.Remove Key
        End If
    Next Key
    Set mdict = Nothing
    Erase mData
    
    ' Loop through the remaining keys of the slave dictionary
    ' and populate the destination array accordingly.
    
    For Each Key In sdict.Keys ' not found in master
        sr = sdict(Key)
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
        Next c
    Next Key
    Set sdict = Nothing
    Erase sData
                
    ' Destination
                
    Dim dwb As Workbook: ' Destination (Summary)
    Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & SUMMARY_FILE_NAME)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(SUMMARY_SHEET_NAME)
    
    With dws.Range("A2").Resize(dr, cCount)
        .Value = dData
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    End With
     
    'dws.Save ' save and leave open
    'or:
    'dws.Close SaveChanges:=True ' save and close
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Differences retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```